# Inner Join in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2007, inner-join, vb.net-2010

```
#Region "FillListView"
    Sub FillListview()
        LV.Items.Clear()
        myqry = "SELECT AccResult.StudNo,Exercises.ID from AccResult INNER JOIN Exercises ON AccResult.StudNo = Exercises.ID ORDER BY AccResult.FirstName,AccResult.YrandSec Asc;"
        mycmd = New OleDbCommand(myqry, con)
        con.Open()
        mydr = mycmd.ExecuteReader
        While mydr.Read
              With LV
                .Items.Add(mydr("StudNo"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(mydr("CNumber"))
                    .Add(mydr("FirstName"))
                    .Add(mydr("LastName"))
                    .Add(mydr("YrandSec"))
                    .Add(mydr("Exer1"))
                    .Add(mydr("Exer2"))
                    .Add(mydr("Exer3"))
                    .Add(mydr("Exer4"))
                    .Add(mydr("Exer5"))
                End With
            End With
        End While
        con.Close()
    End Sub
#End Region
```

`AccResult` is the name of my first table and `Exercises` is the second.
My PK for `AccResult` is `StudNo` and for `Exercises` is `ID`.
How can I join these two tables to display in `ListView`?

`AccResult` Table:

```
StudNo (PK)
CNumber
FirstName
LastName
YrandSec
```

`Exercises` Table:

```
ID (PK)
StudNo
Exer1
Exer2
Exer3
Exer4
Exer5
```

Comment: 1. Are you using MySQL or MS Access? You've tagged your question with both products, but which one is actually used to execute the query in your question? 2. Does the query itself work? I mean, does it produce any errors or not? In other words, what specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JOIN condition is incorrect.

```
AccResult INNER JOIN Exercises ON AccResult.StudNo = Exercises.ID
```

is joining the primary key of the parent table (AccResult.StudNo) with the primary key of the child table (Exercises.ID). You need to join the primary key of the parent table (AccResult.StudNo) with the **foreign key** of the child table (Exercises.StudNo), i.e.,

```
AccResult INNER JOIN Exercises ON AccResult.StudNo = Exercises.StudNo
```

Comment: @user2926827 that's because your SELECT statement only returns `AccResult.StudNo,Exercises.ID` so there is no column named `CNumber` in the result set. You will need to add the remaining fields to the column list (between the SELECT and FROM keywords) so they will be available in `mydr` for you to use.

Comment: myqry = "SELECT AccResult.StudNo,AccResult.CNumber,AccResult.FirstName,AccResult.LastName,AccResult.YrandSec,Exercises.Exer1,Exercises.Exer2,Exercises.Exer3,Exercises.Exer4,Exercises.Exer5, from AccResult INNER JOIN Exercises ON AccResult.StudNo = Exercises.StudNo ORDER BY AccResult.FirstName,AccResult.YrandSec Asc;"



ERROR:
The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Comment: @user2926827 that error is caused by the extra comma (`,`) between `Exer5` and `from`.

Comment: sir thank you so much it works. but how about to populate the listview??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question correctly, but it looks like the query only select to columns :

```
myqry = "SELECT AccResult.StudNo,Exercises.ID from AccResult..."
```

then the code try to display all columns. Try to select all columns instead :

```
myqry = "SELECT * from AccResult..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myqry = "SELECT AccResult.StudNo,Exercises.ID, Exer1, Exer2, Exer3, Exer4, Exer5 from AccResult INNER JOIN Exercises ON AccResult.StudNo = Exercises.ID ORDER BY AccResult.FirstName,AccResult.YrandSec Asc;"
```

Comment: Give me an Error sir. Type mismatch in expression.